# Using existing map file for resolving symbols locations

Tags: gcc, linker, symbol-table

I have an executable cross compiled for a micro controller and code is actually pic. I want to write a different program with symbols resolved from the map file of previous executable. Is it possible ?

Why I need it :

This way I can just upload program anywhere in the RAM and call it via function pointer during runtime.